# Term for a moral test to see if someone is honest?

Tags: ethics

Is there any terminology for the general situation where a test is carried out to check if someone is honest?

A really simple example could be when you know the answer to something and you know someone else knows the answer, and you ask someone what they think, and they may or may not give you the honest answer.

Is there a name in philosophy or psychology for this type of moral test? (and if not, is there a canonical example that could be referred to instead?)

Comment: You mean, for example, if I see somebody stealing and then ask him? Or whatever I saw him doing and then ask about)?

Comment: @StarsratS yes, perfect example.

Comment: Good question! To be honest (good word in this context), I really dont know... May I can make something up but thats not usually here I guess... In a lie detector test you dont know in advance. "Checking"  maybe?

Comment: "Statement Analysis" may be close to what you are looking for. More here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_analysis

Answer (score 2):

Integrity Test.

Typically an employment-related test.

They took over from polygraphs after the introduction of the Employee Polygraph Protection Act.

There are at least two types: overt and personality-oriented.

They are subject to some valid criticisms:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employment_integrity_testing#Criticisms

There's a link to a test via Psychology Today, here: https://www.psychologytoday.com/au/tests/career/integrity-and-work-ethics-test